# Is there a way to find hourly averages in pandas timeframes that do not start from even hours?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (python) indexed with timestamps roughly every 10 seconds. I want to find hourly averages, but all functions I find start their averaging at even hours (e.g. hour 9 includes data from 08.00:00 to 08:59:50). Let's say I have the dataframe below.

```
Timestamp              value    data   
2022-01-01 00:00:00    0.0      5.31
2022-01-01 00:00:10    0.0      0.52
2022-01-01 00:00:20    1.0      9.03
2022-01-01 00:00:30    1.0      4.37
2022-01-01 00:00:40    1.0      8.03
                      ... 
2022-01-01 13:52:30    1.0      9.75
2022-01-01 13:52:40    1.0      0.62
2022-01-01 13:52:50    1.0      3.58
2022-01-01 13:53:00    1.0      8.23
2022-01-01 13:53:10    1.0      3.07
Freq: 10S, Length: 5000, dtype: float64
```

So what I want to do:

1. Only look at data where we have data that consistently through 1 hour has a value of 1
2. Find an hourly average of these hours (could e.g. be between 01:30:00-02:29:50 and 11:16:30 - 12:16:20)..

I hope I made my problem clear enough. How do I do this?

**EDIT:**

Maybe the question was a bit unclear phrased.
I added a third column `data`, which is what I want to find the mean of. I am only interested in time intervals where,  `value = 1` consistently through one hour, the rest of the data can be excluded.

**EDIT #2:**

A bit of background to my problem: I have a sensor giving me data every 10 seconds. For data to be "approved" certain requirements are to be fulfilled (`value` in this example), and I need the hourly averages (and preferably timestamps for when this occurs). So in order to maximize the number of possible hours to include in my analysis, I would like to find full hours even if they don't start at an even timestamp.

Comment: Could you give an example of what kind of output you are expecting?  Do you want a sliding window of 1 hour in time where are values are 1.0?

Comment: I think question is very unclear. with 10S data testing solution for 1 hour is really problematic. Is for testing change hour average to minute average? Also mean of `1` is always `1`, so missing expected ouput what need exactly.

Comment: Whats happens with datetimes outside hour interval? Are excluded?

Comment: Lets say there is a stretch of 1.5 hours, where `value == 1`. should the average be calculated for one hour or the whole timespan? Similiar Question: what should be done if such a stretch is multiple hours long?

Comment: @Sandwichnick each sampling period need to be one hour. If we have a stretch that is 1.5 hours, I only care about the first hour. If we have multiple hours in one "stretch", it is to be divided into as many full hours as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want a conditional mean - calculate the mean per hour of the `data` column *conditional* on the `value` column being all `1` for every 10s row in that hour.

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, the steps to do this are:

**Create a grouping column**

This is your 'hour' column that can be created by

```
df['hour'] = df.Timestamp.hour
```

**Create condition**

Now we've got a column to identify groups we can check which groups are eligible - only those with `value` consistently equal to `1`. If we have 10s intervals and it's per hour then if we group by hour and *sum* this column then we should get 360 as there are 360 10s intervals per hour.

**Group and compute**

We can now group and use the *aggregate* function to:

- sum the `value` column to evaluate against our condition
- compute the mean of the `data` column to return for the valid hours

```
# group and aggregate
df_mean = df[['hour', 'value', 'data']].groupby('hour').aggregate({'value': 'sum', 'data': 'mean'})
# apply condition
df_mean = df_mean[df_mean['value'] == 360]
```

That's it - you are left with a dataframe that contains the mean value of `data` for only the hours where you have a complete hour of `value=1`.

If you want to augment this so you don't have to start with the grouping as per hour starting as 08:00:00-09:00:00 and maybe you want to start as 08:00:10-09:00:10 then the solution is simple - **augment the grouping column but don't change anything else in the process.**

To do this you can use `datetime.timedelta` to shift things forward or back so that `df.Timestamp.hour` can still be leveraged to keep things simple.

**Infer grouping from data**

One final idea - if you want to infer which hours on a *rolling* basis you have complete data for then you can do this with a rolling sum - this is even easier. You:

- compute the rolling sum of `value` and mean of `data`
- only select where `value` is equal to 360

```
df_roll = df.rolling(360).aggregate({'value': 'sum', 'data': 'mean'})
df_roll = df_roll[df_roll['value'] == 360]
```

Comment: how this solutio aggregate by intervals `01:30:00-02:29:50 and 11:16:30 - 12:16:20` like need OP?

Comment: Edited to contain final bit on rolling solution to infer the complete groups from the data. What do you think?

Comment: it is wrong, OP dont need rolling

Comment: This is almost a copy of my own attempt, with the same issue. The first approach only gives back mean for even hours (from e.g. 9.00-10.00), which is a problem seeing I don't know at what times my condition will be fulfilled. I don't think rolling gives what I want either...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You need [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with an `offset`.

##### Make some test data

Please make sure to provide meaningful test data next time.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# One day in 10 second intervals
index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/2/2018', freq='10S')
df = pd.DataFrame({"data": np.random.random(len(index))}, index=index)

# This will set the first part of the data to 1, the rest to 0
df["value"] = (df.index < "2018-01-01 10:00:10").astype(int)
```

This is what we got:

```py
>>> df 
                         data  value
2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.377082      1
2018-01-01 00:00:10  0.574471      1
2018-01-01 00:00:20  0.284629      1
2018-01-01 00:00:30  0.678923      1
2018-01-01 00:00:40  0.094724      1
...                       ...    ...
2018-01-01 23:59:20  0.839973      0
2018-01-01 23:59:30  0.890321      0
2018-01-01 23:59:40  0.426595      0
2018-01-01 23:59:50  0.089174      0
2018-01-02 00:00:00  0.351624      0
```

##### Get the mean per hour with an offset

Here is a small function that checks if all `value` rows in the slice are equal to 1 and returns the `mean` if so, otherwise it (implicitly) returns `None`.

```py
def get_conditioned_average(frame):
    if frame.value.eq(1).all():
        return frame.data.mean()
```

Now just apply this to hourly slices, starting, e.g., at 10 seconds after the full hour.

```py
df2 = df.resample('H', offset='10S').apply(get_conditioned_average)
```

This is the final result:

```py
>>> df2
2017-12-31 23:00:10    0.377082
2018-01-01 00:00:10    0.522144
2018-01-01 01:00:10    0.506536
2018-01-01 02:00:10    0.505334
2018-01-01 03:00:10    0.504431
...             ...         ...
2018-01-01 19:00:10         NaN
2018-01-01 20:00:10         NaN
2018-01-01 21:00:10         NaN
2018-01-01 22:00:10         NaN
2018-01-01 23:00:10         NaN
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a neat solution and indeed the answer to the topic question (badly phrased of me). But don't I have to manually select from which timestamp I want to take the mean from here? I mean, I don't know that `value` is  `1` at an offset of 10S? Is it possible to make an offset variable that is not static, but varies e.g. the first time `value` = 1`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but would it work to filter out all rows up to the first row where the value is 1? An example of an input and an expected output would be really helpful...